# R - how to add N number of rows to each grouping of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

| EventID | Business | Region | Loss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | AUS | 620 |
| 383 | A | AUS | 1232 |
| 123 | B | AUS | 620 |
| 123 | C | AUS | 1232 |
| 499 | A | JPN | 620 |
| 499 | B | JPN | 1232 |
| 522 | B | JPN | 620 |
| 771 | A | MEX | 1232 |
| 919 | A | MEX | 620 |
| 771 | B | MEX | 1232 |
| 800 | B | MEX | 620 |
| 993 | C | MEX | 1232 |
| 1772 | A | SWE | 620 |
| 2004 | C | SWE | 1232 |
| 2193 | A | USA | 620 |
| 3384 | A | USA | 1232 |
| 2193 | A | USA | 620 |
| 4026 | B | USA | 1232 |
| 6002 | C | USA | 620 |
| 6283 | C | USA | 1232 |

What I would like to do is insert rows so that each grouping by Business and Region has 10 additional Events when counting individual instances of EventID.

For example this is what it looks like when Business A is grouped:

| Business | Region | Event_Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | AUS | 2 |
| A | JPN | 1 |
| A | MEX | 2 |
| A | SWE | 1 |
| A | USA | 3 |

I want the original dataframe to have 10 extra rows inserted per Business-Region grouping with blank EventID and Loss fields, which would make the grouped df look like this:

| Business | Region | Event_Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | AUS | 12 |
| A | JPN | 11 |
| A | MEX | 12 |
| A | SWE | 11 |
| A | USA | 13 |

Tried some solutions from other stackoverflow q's like this one:

```
LSM_Re_Events_Less_100 <- LSM_Re %>% right_join(LSM_Re_Events, by=c("LineOfBusiness", "Peril", "Region")) %>%
  select(YearID, EventID, LineOfBusiness, Peril, Region, Loss) %>%
  xtabs(formula = Loss ~ YearID + EventID + LineOfBusiness + Peril + Region) %>% as.data.frame()
```

But I haven't found anything that describes how to add a specific number of rows based on each grouping.

Comment: Can't you just add 10 to the event count after summarising?

Answer (score 0):

You can repeatedly select the non-duplicate rows. E.g.,

```
rbind(
  df,
  df[rep(which(!duplicated(select(df, Business, Region))), each = 10),] %>%
    mutate(EventID = NA, Loss = NA)
)
```